# Attempting to display multiple png files in one Qt Window using CPP

Tags: c++, qt5

I am using Qt5 in cpp, and I am attempting to display multiple png files in one window. All my attempts to date, will place one png image on top of the other

The png file names are passed to the program as arguments

```
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   QGraphicsScene scene;
   QGraphicsView view(&scene);
   QGraphicsPixmapItem item1(QPixmap((char*) argv[1]));
   scene.addItem(&item1);
   QGraphicsPixmapItem item2(QPixmap((char*) argv[2]));
   scene.addItem(&item2);
   view.show();
   a.exec();
```

Reading through the Qt documentation, I thought QGraphicsItemGroup might hand this for me. It did not make a difference.

```
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   QGraphicsScene scene;
   QGraphicsView view(&scene);

   QGraphicsPixmapItem item2(QPixmap((char*) argv[1]));
   QGraphicsPixmapItem item3(QPixmap((char*) argv[2]));
   QGraphicsItemGroup grp;
   grp.addToGroup(&item2);
   grp.addToGroup(&item3);
   scene.addItem(&grp);
   view.show();
   a.exec();
```

These are both examples both build, but both have the same error, one png is on top of the other. I am trying to get both png files to show in the same window.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the 2 images next to one another, you need to control their position yourself.

Have a look at QGraphicsAnchorLayout in
[Simple Anchor Layout Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-simpleanchorlayout-example.html)

and QGraphicsLayout in 
[Graphics View Flow Layout Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-flowlayout-example.html)

Comment: sorry it took me so long to get back, this looks helpful.